# Meromorphic Function Question

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently trying to solve this question:

> Let $f$ be meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ whose only pole is at $0$. Suppose that $f$ is bounded outside the unit disk $\Delta_1(0)$. Show that $f(z) = \frac{P(z)}{z^k}$ for some polynomial $p(z)$ and some integer $k$.

My initial thought is that away from $0$, $f$ has a power series expansion 
$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-c)^n$ centred at $c$. . This is where I get stuck though, the boundedness assumption is throwing me off. Any ideas?

Comment: Liouville only applies to bounded *entire* functions, i.e. functions that holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @SpamIAm Thanks. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Laurent expansion at $0$. Apply Lioville at the regular part, hence it is constant.

By the way, there is a much more general result. Meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere are rational functions. Google shows this blog entry: http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/meromorphic-functions-on-the-riemann-sphere-pt-i/

Comment: Yeah, that's such a nice result!